# rel nofollow and direct views in GA

Tags: google-analytics

Is rel=nofollow link causes google analytics to treat this as direct view?
Because in my test, i reach my page from a nofollow link, and GA doesn't show a referer

I wanted to know if there is some problem with my test, or is this a known issue?

Comment: Can you provide more specifics about the test? Was the traffic https to http? That would have concealed the referrer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might just be an issue with your test.  `referer` information is sent by the browser, not by the page containing the `nofollow` link.  So as long as your browser (or your clients browser) reports referer information, it will not matter if the link contained `rel=nofollow`.

Check out the wiki for more information on how HTTP Referer works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Specifically, under the section of `Referer Hiding`, it reads:

> Most web browsers do not send the referer field when they are
>   instructed to redirect using the "Refresh" field. This does not
>   include some versions of Opera and many mobile web browsers